# The max product of consecutive elements in an array

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this algorithm question during my onsite interview. Since I was not asked to sign NDA, I post it here for an answer.

Given an array of **REAL** numbers that does not contain 0, find the consecutive elements that yield max product. The algorithm should run in linear time

I have considered the following approach:
Use two arrays. First one is to use DP idea to record the current max **absolute value** product, the second array to record the number of negative elements met so far. The final result should be the largest max absolute value and the number of negative numbers be even.

I thought my method will work, but was interrupted during coding saying it will not work. 
Please let me know what is missing in the above approach.

Comment: Hint: assume you only have positive numbers. What does the problem reduce to if you take the logarithm (any base) of each number? Now, how can you handle negative numbers as well?

Comment: Given the requirement for consecutive elements, and assuming an odd number of negatives, you'd need to try from both ends.

Comment: (This is assuming that "consecutive elements" has an implied "N" in front of it, not an implied "2".)

Comment: Are negative values allowed?

Comment: Doesn't REAL mean floating-point? I do not understand why everyone is assuming INTEGER.

Comment: @Gupta, in your case, it should be 120, [4,5,6] is the answer

Comment: @Gupta: there should not be a 0 in your example, as I mentioned explicitly. Also, the array should be size>1

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to use @IVlad's hint to come up with a solution. So far I have figured out that if all numbers are positive, then the problem reduces to taking the log(anybase) of every number in the array and then finding the max sum of consecutive elements of the array. However I have not yet thought of a way to handle negative numbers. I am working on it.

Comment: You're not making sense.  How does using logs make it any different from simply multiplying?  And, assuming an even number of negatives, why wouldn't the solution just be the product of all elements in the array?  And with odd negatives it would be the product up to the last negative, starting from either end.

Comment: (Ah, yes!  Since these are real one needs to be concerned about values less than 1 (but still positive).  That does make it messier.)

Comment: Btw Jin, this is probably why your solution does not work: you don't know from which subarray the maximum value comes from, and hence you don't know how many negative numbers are there. consider the array `[2, -0.7, 2, 2]`. Your DP will produce `[2, 2, 2.8, 5.6]` and the count of negative numbers `[0, 1, 1, 1]` and so your output will be `2` where it should be `4` (note that `4` does not even appear in your DP array).

Comment: Btw, are you sure that the problem wants you to multiply at least two elements? I'm a bit unsure on this since the original maximum subarray problem allows a single element sum, which is not the case here.
Note that the product of one number is the number itself. So don't you think for the case `[2, 60, 0.0001, 121]` the answer should be `121`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The algorithm is indeed O(n). When iterating the array, use a variable to store the max value found so far, a variable to store the max value of subarray that ends at a[i], and another variable to store minimum value that ends at a[i] to treat negative values.

```
float find_maximum(float arr[], int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return NAN;

    float max_at = arr[0];  // Maximum value that ends at arr[i]
    float min_at = arr[0];  // Minimum value that ends at arr[i]
    float max_value = max_at;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        float prev_max_at = max_at, prev_min_at = min_at;
        max_at = max(arr[i], arr[i] * prev_min_at, arr[i] * prev_max_at);
        min_at = min(arr[i], arr[i] * prev_min_at, arr[i] * prev_max_at);
        max_value = max(max_value, max_at);
    }
    return max_value;
}
```

Comment: Really nice job. O(n) and extremely simple as well. I was thinking way too hard. Kudos to you and +1 sir.

Comment: Although this one will output `0.1` for `[0.1, -3, 0.1]`, which I believe should be the case, not as OP has mentioned

Comment: @justhalf Well even if it's not the case then he could just edit the arguments to his `max` function and take out `arr[i]` and it would work if the subarray must be at least two elements.

Comment: If you are saying the product must be at least of two elements, we can simply update the algorithm:
In the beginning: max_at = arr[0] * arr[1];
Then:
max_at = max(arr[i] * arr[i-1], arr[i] * prev_min_at, arr[i] * prev_max_at);
The same for min_at

Comment: @Shashank: Nope. How about the array in the comments: `[60, 2, -0.000000001, 99999]` or basically any array containing single isolated highest element

Comment: @Echevil: yes, I'm not saying that we can't update it. It's just we might need to clarify this with OP, and if it's really at least two elements, then we do need to update the code. That's my point. =D

Comment: He accounts for "single isolated highest element" by including `arr[i]` as an argument to his max function. His code is just fine and easily modifiable to make it work with a bound of length(subarray) >=2.

Comment: @Shashank, yes, his code is fine and easily modifiable, I agree. I'm just making my point to your (apparently edited) comment that we can just simply consider special case of two elements. =)

Comment: This is correct, passed all leetcode test case.. Cool

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a variant of the Kadane algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) who runs with constant extra memory and linear in the size of the problem (no extra array,...)

If only strict positive numbers are given:

```py
def max_subarray_mul(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = 1
    for x in A:
        if x > 0
            max_ending_here = max(1,max_ending_here*x)
            max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```

I'm still working on the part with negative numbers

Or a more expensive (in time) method is the following, but this will work with negative numbers:

```py
def max_subarray_mul(A):
    max_so_far = 1
    n = length(A)
    for i in 1...n:
        x = A[i]
        tmp = x
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far,tmp)
        for j in i+1...n:
          tmp = tmp*A[j]
          max_so_far = max(max_so_far,tmp)
    return max_so_far
```

Which runs in constant memory and `O(n²)` time

Comment: if `x > 0`, `max_ending_here`, assuming it means what its name implies, can be just `x` itself and not `max_ending_here*x`. For example: `0.3 2.2`. `0.3 * 2.2 < 2.2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using python notations:

- compute `min( prod( v[ 0: ] ), prod( v[ 1: ] ), ...,  prod( v[ -1 ] ) )` and `max( prod( v[ 0: ] ), prod( v[ 1: ] ), ...,  prod( v[ -1 ] ) )` in O(n)
- compute recursively the max product based on the fact that `maxpro(v) = max( maxpro(v[:-1]) * max( prod( v[ 0: ] ), prod( v[ 1: ] ), ...,  prod( v[ -1 ] ) )`. This is O(n) too

Here is the code:

```
#
n = 5
vmax = 10

#
v = nr.randint( 1, vmax, n )
v *= nr.randint( 0, 2, n ) * 2 - 1
#
print v

#
prod_res = np.zeros( ( 2, n ), int )
prod_res[ 0, 0 ] = prod_res[ 1, 0 ] = v[ 0 ]
for i in xrange( 1, n ) :
    prod_res[ 0, i ] = min( v[ i ], prod_res[ 1, i-1 ] * v[ i ], prod_res[ 0, i-1 ] * v[ i ] )
    prod_res[ 1, i ] = max( v[ i ], prod_res[ 1, i-1 ] * v[ i ], prod_res[ 0, i-1 ] * v[ i ] )
#
print prod_res

#
def maxpro_naive( v ) :
    return v[ 0 ] if ( len( v ) == 1 ) else max( maxpro_naive( v[ :-1 ] ), prod_res[ 1, len(v) -1 ] )
#
print maxpro_naive( v )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring negative numbers for the moment...

Let `A[i..j]` mean `A[i]*A[i+1]*...*A[j]`

The problem is to find `max(A[i..j])`

Notice that `A[i..j] = A[0..j] / A[0..i-1]`

So if we calculate `A[0..x]` for all x.

We can then determine `max(A[i..j]) = max(A[0..x]) / min(A[0..y])`

Comment: Counter-example: `A = [5, 0.1]`. Then `max(A[0..x]) == A[0..0] == 5` and `min(A[0..y]) == A[0..1] == 5 * 0.1 == 0.5`. Thus your method gives result 5 / 0.5 == 10.0 when the actual solution should be 5.

Answer (score 0):

Taking care of the thing if there are no 1's in the array and the product coming should not be 1 in that case.
Here is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int max(int x, int y)
{ return (y > x)? y : x; }
int min(int x, int y)
{ return (y < x)? y : x; }
bool search(int a[],int k,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==k)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int maxSubArrayProduct(int a[], int size)
{
   int maxpos = 1, minneg=1, i;
   int pro_max = 1;

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
        if(a[i]<0)
        {
            int temp=maxpos;
            maxpos=max(maxpos,minneg*a[i]);
            minneg=min(minneg,temp*a[i]);
        }
        if(a[i]==0)
        {maxpos=1;minneg=1;}
        if(a[i]>0)
        {
            maxpos=maxpos*a[i];
            minneg=min(minneg,minneg*a[i]);
        }
        if(pro_max<maxpos)
        pro_max=maxpos;
   }
   return pro_max;
}

/* Driver program to test maxSubArrayProduct */
int main()
{
   int a[] =  {-1,0,1};
   int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
   int start=0,end=0;
   int max_pro = maxSubArrayProduct(a, n);
   if(max_pro==1)
   if(search(a,1,n))max_pro=1;
   else max_pro=0;
   printf("Maximum contiguous product is %d\n", max_pro);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In O(n) result. Find the consecutive elements that yield max product, by multiplying each element from left to right and saving them in a list. If the new product is bigger than the last multiply the next element and update the list. If not start a new list and repeat. Algorithm in Python 3.3 :

```
import numpy as np

x = [-500,-400,200,0.1,-100,20,-10,2]

prod_seq_lists = [[x[0], x[1]]]  # Start assuming the first 2 elements have max product and save them in a list
product_result = []  # Contains the product of each list


for e in x[2:]:  # Start for loop from 3rd element
    if x[0] == 0 or x[1] == 0 or e == 0:  # Raise error if there's a 0
        raise IndexError('Found 0')

    temp_b = np.prod(prod_seq_lists[-1])  # Calculate the product of the last list in max_prod_seq
    temp_a = temp_b * e  # Multiply the new_element

    if temp_a >= temp_b:  # If last_list*new_element >= last_list
        prod_seq_lists[-1].append(e)  # Append the new_element in your last_list

        if e == x[-1]:
            product_result.append(temp_a)  # Save the product of the last list

    else:
        product_result.append(temp_b)  # Save the product of each list
        prod_seq_lists.append([e])  # Else, append append the new element in a new_list


print("Your array: ", prod_seq_lists)
print("The list with max product of consecutive elements: ", prod_seq_lists[np.argmax(product_result)])  # Get index of the maximum product and print that list
print("The max product of consecutive elements: ", max(product_result))
```

Returns :

```
Your array:  [[-50, -40, 20], [0.1], [-100], [20], [-10], [90, 1000]]
The list with max product of consecutive elements:  [90, 1000]
The max product of consecutive elements:  90000
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote below code,  for finding  maximum product of adjacent integer values in input array, assuming the product would also be in the int range
it would iterate the loop n/2 times only

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {

    int maxProdct=inputArray[0]*inputArray[1];
//as we have already taken product of first two , start from 3rd and iterate till second last because we are checking the product of i+1 for every i
    for (int i=2; i<inputArray.length-1; i=i+2){
        if(inputArray[i-1]*inputArray[i] >inputArray[i]*inputArray[i+1]){
            if(inputArray[i-1]*inputArray[i]>maxProdct)
                maxProdct =inputArray[i-1]*inputArray[i];
        }
        else if(inputArray[i+1]*inputArray[i] > maxProdct)
            maxProdct=inputArray[i+1]*inputArray[i];



    }
//if its an even array the last element would have been covered while calculating product with second last, otherwise we would check the product for last and second last element and compare with maxProduct
    if(inputArray.length%2 !=0){
        if(maxProdct<inputArray[inputArray.length-1]*inputArray[inputArray.length-2]){
            maxProdct=inputArray[inputArray.length-1]*inputArray[inputArray.length-2];
        }
    }
    return maxProdct;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to solve in *O(n)* and allowed to take two traversals of array and *o(n)* extra space, my below code would work for all *+ve* and *-ve* values in Java.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class largestProductOfTwoNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
        int a[] = { -22, -5, 12, 6, 3, 4, 9, -11, 4, 5, 6, 8, 7, 7 };
        int max = 0;

        int curr = 0;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {

            curr = a[i] * a[i + 1];
            list.add(curr);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i) > max) {
                max = list.get(i);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer assumes all numbers are positive.*

A one-liner solution in python:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

def max_prod(a):
    return max(accumulate(a, lambda x,y: max(x*y, 1), initial=1))
```

This is O(n)-time and O(1)-space.

This algorithm uses `itertools.accumulate` to compute accumulated products from the beginning of the array, dropping back to the empty product 1 if a result is ever lower than 1. Then, we return the maximum product found.

We can test the correctness of the algorithm by generating arrays of random numbers and comparing with a bruteforce solution:

```py
from math import prod
from numpy import random

def brute_force(a):
    return max(prod(a[i:j]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(i,len(a)+1))

for _ in range(1000):
    a = random.random(10) * 3 # array of 10 floats in [0.0..3.0]
    p1 = max_prod(a)
    p2 = brute_force(a)
    if p1 != p2:
        print(a)
        print(list(accumulate(a, lambda x,y: max(x*y, 1), initial=1)))
        print(p1, p2)
        print()
```